# Data transfer between pages

Tags: asp.net, .net

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
    Label1.Text=Request.QueryString["FileNo"].ToString();    
    Label3.Text=Request.QueryString["Sub"].ToString();  
    DDL_U.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["Unit"].ToString();
    DDL_Branch.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["Branch"].ToString();
}
```

This is the `PageLoad` function of `File.aspx` page.
I am getting error on queryString when I debug `File.aspx`

I have two pages named `File.aspx` and `Search.aspx`. What I want to do is to transfer data from `Search.aspx` to `File.aspx`. I am using `queryString` to transfer data and initialising that data to controls on pageload function of File.aspx but my problem is `File.aspx` is my start page so it is giving the error on `querystring`.

Comment: Please add some code samples.

Comment: [What have you tried ?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: You need to do something like if(querystring == null) don't access it

Comment: What error? You neglect to tell us that which would help.

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Label1.Text=Request.QueryString["FileNo"].ToString();
            Label3.Text=Request.QueryString["Sub"].ToString();
            DDL_U.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["Unit"].ToString();
            DDL_Branch.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["Branch"].ToString();
            
            
        }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you need to take care of query string when it is not available or null. So write your code inside this

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.QueryString["FileNo"] != null)
  {
    Label1.Text = Request.QueryString["FileNo"].ToString();
  }
  if (Request.QueryString["Sub"] != null)
  {
    Label3.Text = Request.QueryString["Sub"].ToString();
  }
  if (Request.QueryString["Unit"] != null)
  {
    DDL_U.SelectedValue = Request.QueryString["Unit"].ToString();
  }
  if (Request.QueryString["Branch"] != null)
  {
    DDL_Branch.SelectedValue=Request.QueryString["Branch"].ToString();
  }
}
```